# Parallels Desktop: Option not available: "Install macOS Using the Recovery Partition"

Tags: big-sur, virtualization, parallels-desktop, apple-silicon

- I'm on a Mac Mini M1 with Big Sur 11.3.1
- Fresh trial install of Parallels Desktop 16.5.0 Pro Edition
- I'm not seeing the option "Install macOS Using the Recovery Partition", as described in their [KB article](https://kb.parallels.com/cn/125105).

[image]

My screen looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Could't confirm this with a quick search, but the recovery partition is different with M1, maybe this creates problems?

Comment: @X_841 I have no idea. Parallels is advertising M1 readyness...

Answer (score 1):

Parallels support chat told me that macOS vm's are not (yet) supported on M1 processors.

I should follow https://kb.parallels.com/125053.

Comment: Also deep inthe press release saying the fully suport the M1 https://www.parallels.com/news/press-releases/show/2021-pd16-5-m1chip/ s they say macOS Big Sur in a VM is a feature that Parallels hopes to add support for in Parallels Desktop later this year.

Comment: @mmmmmm Thanks for digging that out. I cannot create any macOS vm, not just Big Sur.

Comment: Well on an M1 that is not surprising only Big Sur runs on a M1 everything else requires an Intel or PPC chip. Parallels is a virtual machine so only runs the same CPU as the host - for a different CPU you need an emulator e.g. QEMU.

Comment: Makes sense. Looks like I'll have to buy an Intel mac or get this to work on VirtualBox somehow. Not the first time I'm regretting that M1 purchase by now. I'm getting too old to play early adopter *sigh.

Comment: Virtual Box will have the same issue - but I don't think they are on Arm yet. Yes you need an Intel box

Comment: VirtualBox on my Windows Intel machine.